# How to merge many reactions into one

Tags: dart, mobx

I have many reactions, and all reactions are calling the same function.

```
late List<ReactionDisposer> _disposers;
_disposers = [
  reaction((_) => gameMode, (_) => _apply),
  reaction((_) => level, (_) => _apply),
  reaction((_) => round, (_) => _apply),
  reaction((_) => timeoutInSec, (_) => _apply),
  reaction((_) => hostage, (_) => _apply),
  reaction((_) => upTime, (_) => _apply),
];
```

How to merge in one reaction like below?

```
_disposers = [
  reaction((_) => gameMode|level|round|timeoutInSec|hostage|upTime, (_) => _apply),
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this code:

```dart
final _disposers = [
  gameMode,
  level, 
  round,
  timeoutInSec,
  hostage,
  uptime,
].map((func) =>
  reaction((_) => func, (_) => apply))
    .toList();
```